# Under what conditions is app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF); ignored?

Tags: spring-boot

I am calling `app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);` in my application but I still get a banner.

My code:

```
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MyApp.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    app.setAdditionalProfiles("foobar");
```

Output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.8.RELEASE)
```

Expected output:

```
(nothing)
```

What could be causing this?!

Comment: can you check with spring.main.banner-mode=off once in properties file whether it works.

Comment: yeah that works. I would like to know why the documented code example doesn't.